# UUID data type in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, uuid

I need to change specification of the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE STAGE.STG_AAA_PROFILES
(
  SUBSCRIBER         INTEGER,
  USERNAME           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  GROUP_ID           INTEGER,
  PROFILE_ID         INTEGER,
  STATUS             INTEGER,
  PASSWORD_TYPE      INTEGER,
  EXPIRATION         DATE
)
```

I have to make it look like:

```
CREATE TABLE STAGE.STG_AAA_PROFILES
(
  SUBSCRIBER         UID,
  USERNAME           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  GROUP_ID           INTEGER,
  PROFILE_ID         UID,
  STATUS             INTEGER,
  PASSWORD_TYPE      INTEGER,
  EXPIRATION         DATE
)
```

How to alter table to replace integer with UID data type???

Answer (score 6):

Oracle does not have a UUID data type.

Either use:

- `VARCHAR2(36)` to store the UUID as a formatted hexadecimal string (32 hexadecimal characters and 4 dashes); or
- `RAW(16)` to store the UUID as 16 bytes (128 bits).

> How to alter table to replace integer with UID data type?

```sql
ALTER TABLE STAGE.STG_AAA_PROFILES ADD subscriber_uuid VARCHAR2(36);
```

Then convert the existing `subscriber` column from integer to a UUID or generate UUIDs for the rows in the table. Finally:

```sql
ALTER TABLE STAGE.STG_AAA_PROFILES DROP COLUMN subscriber;
ALTER TABLE STAGE.STG_AAA_PROFILES RENAME COLUMN subscriber_uuid TO subscriber;
```

Comment: So, you say, if I try to do this way, it wouldn't worki it out:

` ALTER TABLE STAGE.STG_AAA_PROFILES DROP COLUMN subscriber;`

`ALTER TABLE STAGE.STG_AAA_PROFILES (ADD subscriber INTEGER AS UUID GENERATED BY DEFAULT );`

and second question for you: in the current specification, column subscriber has integer as datatype, not varchar2 as you put above, I suppose that column subscriber_uuid has to be integer???

Comment: @MikiNK `ALTER TABLE STAGE.STG_AAA_PROFILES (ADD subscriber INTEGER AS UUID)` is not valid syntax [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PQGMWB1s).

Comment: @MikiNK Please read the start of the question; Oracle does **NOT** have a (U)UID data type and you normally either use `VARCHAR2(36)` or `RAW(16)` to store a UUID. While it may be possible to store a UUID as an integer, 2^128 ~= 3e38 is close to the maximum value that a `NUMBER` data type (which `INTEGER` is a sub-type of) can store. Why do you think that you need to use an integer for a UUID?

Comment: Ok, I got it...Thanks a lot @MTO...you really helped me out.

Comment: just one more thing...should I use 
ALTER TABLE STAGE.STG_AAA_PROFILES ADD subscriber_uuid VARCHAR2(36)
 AS UUID GENERATED BY DEFAULT??

Or without "AS UUID GENERATED BY DEFAULT??" part?

Comment: @MikiNK No, they are both invalid syntax and it will not work [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PTHnnY2e). Oracle does not support automatic generation of UUIDs in the DDL statement. Either do it manually or write a trigger.

Comment: Ok...and I am required to make it varchar2(50)...it doensn't affect the statement???

ALTER TABLE STAGE.STG_AAA_PROFILES ADD subscriber_uuid VARCHAR2(50);

this would be ok?

Comment: @MikiNK A UUID is a 128 bit binary value that is normally either stored as 16 bytes or as a hexadecimal string which would need 32 hexadecimal characters and is commonly formatted as `FFFFFFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFF` which, with the 4 dashes, would require 36 characters. I don't know why you want to use 50 characters when the maximum you are ever likely to store is 36 characters but if that is what you are required to use then use `VARCHAR2(50)` (just be careful you do not get invalid UUIDs stored in the column).

Comment: When I run the following:
ALTER TABLE STAGE.STG_AAA_PROFILES DROP COLUMN subscriber;

I got this output:
ORA-39726: unsupported add/drop column operation on compressed tables

Comment: @MikiNK **YOU** can very quickly find the solution if you search the internet for that error message (which is to uncompress the table first).

Comment: yeah, I already did it...thank a lot again :)

Comment: You might try `default on null sys_guid()` in place of a trigger.